# Storing Cookie for Apollo in Kotlin Jetpack Compose

Tags: typescript, kotlin, apollo

I am trying to code this auth system for kotlin app using apollo client with firebase. We have built our web and iOS apps and haven't had any trouble storing the cookie.

I have this as my constructor for the client in kotlin

```kotlin
return ApolloClient.Builder().serverUrl("http://10.0.2.2:4000/graphql").okHttpClient(OkHttpClient()).build()
```

and I have this in my index.ts file in my api

```js
app.use(
        session({
            name: "qid",
            store: new FirestoreStore({ dataset: firestore }),
            secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET as string,
            resave: false,
            proxy: true,
            cookie: {
                maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365 * 10,
                httpOnly: true,
                secure: process.env.PROD == "true",
                sameSite: process.env.PROD == "true" ? "none" : 'lax',

            },
            saveUninitialized: false,

        })
    )
```

my issue is that the session cookie is not being stored in the kotlin app. any suggestions for how to get my apollo client to store that cookie?

Answer (score 1):

well my solution to this  is using a class implements cookieJar interface [image]

and you can add this class to your apollo client like this

[image]